# ML Model giving me enormous results after training

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I've got a pretty small dataset for training [here](https://uinedu-my.sharepoint.com/personal/26636_myoffice_site/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B07a5ec65-05c9-4445-ad3b-9852eba9694a%7D&action=default&slrid=62243e9f-e04a-a000-c95f-736ded9652ee&originalPath=aHR0cHM6Ly91aW5lZHUtbXkuc2hhcmVwb2ludC5jb20vOng6L2cvcGVyc29uYWwvMjY2MzZfbXlvZmZpY2Vfc2l0ZS9FV1hzcFFmSkJVVkVyVHVZVXV1cGFVb0JPN2tZOG4xVDVqLThJN2tfVjJ6ek1RP3J0aW1lPXNZOG8xTGJHMTBn&cid=527a30fe-f1d2-4e58-b05c-93daf1ee5d66), and I'm training the model as below:-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn import preprocessing

data = pd.read_csv("house.csv")
x=data.iloc[:,0:3]
y=data["price"]
sd=preprocessing.scale(x)
#print(sd)
#print(data.head())
#
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(3,)))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.2), loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=["mean_squared_error"])
model.fit(x,y,epochs=50)

yp=model.predict(sd)
data ["pred"] = yp
```

I'm getting weird results from the training how many I increase the learning rate or the epochs

```
> Epoch 50/50 32/47 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss:
> 109420707840.0000 - mean_squared_error: 109420707840.0000 47/47 
>[==============================] - 0s 0us/step - loss:
> 103942317426.3830 - mean_squared_error: 103942316032.0000
```

Even without the preprocessing, I'm still getting some un-reasonable numbers!

Comment: That kind of errors appears when you don't preprocess correctly your data. Also, minimizing learning rate won't make it better because it just makes learning slower. Even so, you can try that to know if your model is changing the parameters of your NN architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You train your model not on the preprocessed data but on the raw data and then you evaluate it on the preprocessed data. The data needs to have the same scales at training and test time.

Maybe print out the statistics (range,mean) of the variable of interest ('price'). I guess the goal is to predict house prices. I assume the unit of the house prices is dollars so these are going to be large numbers. In case your dependent variable is large even small relative errors can lead to large loss values, especially with MSE.

I would recommend normalizing the price data as well and to train the model on the scaled versions of the data x,y

Does the loss at least decrease during training ?

Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I'm already training it on the raw data "model.fit(x,y,epochs=50)"

But preprocessing the price and training on the preprocessed data made the trick, Thanks (y)